# SQLite database migration appears to only partially apply in Espresso test

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-espresso, sqliteopenhelper

We have an SQLite database and a corresponding `SQLiteOpenHelper` subclass. This helper has an `onDowngrade` implementation that I would like to write an Espresso test for.

The full `onDowngrade` implementation is available [here](https://github.com/opendatakit/collect/pull/3250/files#diff-c6a9cd678a1a4f071894e0b4efe6cd92R143). This is a simplified version of it:

```java
@Override
public void onDowngrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS foo_tmp (_id integer primary key, bar text not null, baz text not null);");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO foo_tmp(_id,bar,baz) SELECT _id,bar,baz FROM foo;");
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS foo;");
    db.execSQL("RENAME TABLE foo_tmp TO foo;");
}
```

The test loads a database dump with a very high version number and added or removed columns. It then gets a readable database and ensures that the version has been downgraded to the current expected version and that the column names are the expected column names. The full source is available [here](https://github.com/opendatakit/collect/pull/3250/files#diff-92d86aa728589f6840e393ec7a2d542a). This is what it looks like:

```java
@Test
public void testMigration() throws IOException {
    writeDatabaseFile("database" + File.separator + dbFilename);
    InstancesDatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new InstancesDatabaseHelper();

    SQLiteDatabase db = databaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    assertThat(db.getVersion(), is(InstancesDatabaseHelper.DATABASE_VERSION));

    List<String> newColumnNames = InstancesDatabaseHelper.getInstancesColumnNames(db);

    assertThat(newColumnNames, contains(InstancesDatabaseHelper.CURRENT_VERSION_COLUMN_NAMES));
}
```

Everything works as intended if I manually load the same database dumps into the app. However, when I run this test, it looks like the last `RENAME` in the migration is not executed. If I comment out the last two SQL statements in the migration (dropping the original table and renaming the temporary table to the original table name), I can assert that the temporary table has the expected contents ([here](https://github.com/opendatakit/collect/commit/370917632c0671fbefd4f6c2981aca26ce91377f) is a commit that shows this).

With some experimentation, we have found that adding `databaseHelper.getReadableDatabase().close();` in the test after instantiating the `SQLiteOpenHelper` makes the tests pass. Given that the `onDowngrade` call is wrapped in a transaction, I don't understand how this is possible.

Could this point to a bug in our `onDowngrade` implementation? Is triggering migrations in Espresso tests different in some way?

Comment: Consider using alter table statements.

Comment: @danny117 dropping and recreating tables is necessary when removing columns in SQLite. See https://sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html for more details on alter limitations in SQLite.

Comment: Sqllite can rename table with alter table statement maybe it solves issue with your open close.

Comment: I'm seeing upvotes on this question which surprises me. If you're seeing similar behavior, could you please describe the circumstances?

Answer (score 0):

There probably is a race condition, because SQLite is a shared resource.

eg. when the test runs before the last one `COMMIT` statement was issued.

Wrap it into a [transaction](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html) (also see [Isolation In SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/isolation.html)):

```
if(! BuildConfig.DEBUG) { 
    db.beginTransaction();
} else {
    db.beginTransactionWithListener(new SQLiteTransactionListener() {
        @Override public void onBegin()    {Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onBegin()");}
        @Override public void onCommit()   {Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onCommit()");}
        @Override public void onRollback() {Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onRollback()");}
    });
}

try {

    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS foo_tmp (_id integer primary key, bar text not null, baz text not null);");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO foo_tmp(_id,bar,baz) SELECT _id,bar,baz FROM foo;");
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS foo;");
    db.execSQL("RENAME TABLE foo_tmp TO foo;");
    db.setTransactionSuccessful();

} catch(SQLException e){
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "" + e.getMessage());
} finally {
    db.endTransaction();
}
db.close();
```