# Why ContentProvider returns empty cursors after App update?

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite, android-contentprovider

I have recently rolled out an update for my app and I am getting feedback from *some users* that their data is lost. After some analysis, I have determined that a single content provider which I use always returns an empty cursor.

I haven't change the code for the content provider itself or the code which queries it. Data format did not change. The issue only is observable on a small number of devices and it seems to be limited to Android 6.0 (predominately Samsung, but also some LG devices). It is not only that the initial data is lost, but also **all consequent inserts are not persisted**.

The issue can be resolved by a clean installation of the app (delete + install).

Does anyone have an idea of how can this be fixed/workaround?

I don't think it is relevant, but here is the code:

```
Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(Columns.contentUri(), Columns.ALARM_QUERY_COLUMNS, null, null, Columns.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER);

List<AlarmActiveRecord> alarms = new ArrayList<AlarmActiveRecord>();
try {
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            alarms.add(factory.create(cursor));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
} finally {
    cursor.close();
}
return alarms;
```

And the Content Provider:

```
@Override
public Cursor query(Uri url, String[] projectionIn, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sort) {
    SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

    // Generate the body of the query
    Preconditions.checkArgument(sURLMatcher.match(url) == ALARMS, "Invalid URL %s", url);
    qb.setTables("alarms");

    SQLiteDatabase db = mOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor ret;
    try {
        ret = qb.query(db, projectionIn, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, sort);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        log.e("query failed because of " + e.getMessage() + ", recreating DB");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS alarms");
        // I know this is not nice to call onCreate() by ourselves :-)
        mOpenHelper.onCreate(db);
        ret = qb.query(db, projectionIn, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, sort);
    }
    if (ret != null) {
        ret.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), url);
    }

    return ret;
}
```

And the Database Helper:

```
public class AlarmDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "alarms.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 5;
private final Logger log;

public AlarmDatabaseHelper(Context context, Logger log) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    this.log = log;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // @formatter:off
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE alarms (" +
            "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
            "hour INTEGER, " +
            "minutes INTEGER, " +
            "daysofweek INTEGER, " +
            "alarmtime INTEGER, " +
            "enabled INTEGER, " +
            "vibrate INTEGER, " +
            "message TEXT, " +
            "alert TEXT, " +
            "prealarm INTEGER, " +
            "state STRING);");
    // @formatter:on
    // insert default alarms
    String insertMe = "INSERT INTO alarms " + "(hour, minutes, daysofweek, alarmtime, enabled, vibrate, "
            + "message, alert, prealarm, state) VALUES ";
    db.execSQL(insertMe + "(8, 30, 31, 0, 0, 1, '', '', 0, '');");
    db.execSQL(insertMe + "(9, 00, 96, 0, 0, 1, '', '', 0, '');");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int currentVersion) {
    log.d("Upgrading alarms database from version " + oldVersion + " to " + currentVersion
            + ", which will destroy all old data");
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS alarms");
    onCreate(db);
}

public Uri commonInsert(ContentValues values) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    long rowId = db.insert("alarms", Columns.MESSAGE, values);
    if (rowId < 0) throw new SQLException("Failed to insert row");
    log.d("Added alarm rowId = " + rowId);

    return ContentUris.withAppendedId(Columns.contentUri(), rowId);
}
}
```

Comment: I don't think you had something in your `onUpgrade` method, however, just checking if you have anything related to your database tables in your new release.

Comment: I did not change the database version or the table structure. Most of the users are fine, only a small part is affected.

Comment: Why do you have a `ContentProvider` in the first place? Are you specifically trying to make your data available to other apps? If not, get rid of the `ContentProvider`, as you do not need it.

Comment: I use it as a repository to store alarm data in a table. Previously I have indeed exported this provider, but I don't anymore. I have never thought about replacing this mechanism because it worked fine. Can you suggest any alternative? I have to save from 5 to 50 rows, 10 columns each.

Answer (score 0):

There migration script is causing the described behavior. `DROP TABLE` literally does what it says and so all previously entered records will be lost, unless the old version of the database had been backed up to cloud. This issue might not be limited to Samsung or LG devices, because that part is explicit:

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int currentVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS alarms");
}
```

You'd need to migrate the database from one version to the next; for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57463767/549372).

`Room` also supports [Migrating Room databases](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/migrating-db-versions) (it's just the same scenario).

Comment: Sorry, but you are wrong. First, database version did not change. Therefore onUpgrade will not be called. Second, after dropping the database there is an onCreate call, which puts two rows in the database. This obviously does not happen as the cursor stays empty. After on create it would have had two rows in it.

Comment: @YuriyKulikov `onUpgrade()` might run after APK update and you're not comparing `oldVersion` vs. `currentVersion`. the docs read "Called when the database needs to be upgraded." (whenever this may be).

Comment: Anyhow, in the update method I first drop the database and ADD two rows afterwards. So it can never be empty.